# CCTV News: 海外观察：英国华人抗疫进行时: please correct my transcription

Tags: listening, transcription

I'm working with my teacher to improve my listening skills, so I transcribed a short [CCTV News video](http://tv.cctv.com/2020/04/18/VIDESJ0sAj8mBs8kfMsca2hn200418.shtml) (below; also on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS41OE0vACY)), dated Apr 18, 2020 (2 minutes 31 seconds).  It's about ethnic Chinese people in England during the pandemic.

> 英国有近八十万的华侨华人群体，也是全球重要的留学目的地，又二十二万的中国留学生，疫情之下在英华人的生活中[**huang3(?)**]怎么样？华生的[**qing3ying3(?)**]又受到了哪些的冲击，来看欧洲时报，英国负责人离长的观察。
>
> 疫情的确给在英的华人带来了方方面面的影响。有些华人表示呢？TA们收到了歧视。英国中小学关闭，大学停课呢。使的很都留学生打乱了学习计划，财业和[**liu2(?)**]业都使在英华人的[**止住(?)**]产业，也是说我们自己[**xing2(?)**]影响最大的行业。
>
> 疫情的持续蔓延的也比降[**shi4(?)**]的很多华人的收入打的折扣。以伦敦的唐人街为例，这是最近的景象，只有华人超市还在正常经营，大量的餐厅已经停业。少数的餐厅呢？这在提供外卖服务，但是整个街区呢？非常的冷清。伦敦的唐人街呢？路是中心非常核心的位置，平时的正流量非常的大。这是朋友[**拍手(?)**]两个月前，伦敦的唐人街的景象。和今天的冷清，[**xing2(?)**]成了[**xian4(?)**]面的对[**pi(?)**]。
>
> 面对疫情特别是[**dai4(?)**]早期，在英华人的比，英国民中有着更亲情的认识。我们很早了就带上了口罩。面对英国政府出台的全民居家、隔离政策。在英华人的群体呢？也更自觉的相应和支持，不仅如此呢，英国的华人还积极地向英国医疗机构，捐款[**juan3(?)**]物。
>
> 面对疫情呢？在英华人的群体，[**卫生(?)**]去了很多值得[**qing4(?)**]陪的[**shen4yi4(?)**]。在英的中英师门，自发的组织了。英国中医志愿抗疫行动，为大家提供原厂医治，并为大家寄送抗疫中药。在英化人成为了志愿之组织，为有困难的桥包，和留学生朋友提供帮助。
>
> 这是我今天在朋友群看到的，以为十三岁的华人小留学生选择在超市给老人的可订购时段。在超市门口呢？免费为英国的老人发放口罩。
>
> 病毒是可怕的，但是我相信找大家保持乐观、共同努力一定可以取得这场抗疫战争的胜利。

Would it be possible to proofread this transcription please?

I realize this is a bit of a big ask.  If it saves time, feel free to omit an explanation (I can figure it out).  I don't really need a translation either.

---

*Succinct summary*: Many Chinese people/students are in England.  Reports of discrimination; schools etc. are closed; study plans in chaos; industries are suffering; incomes are dropping; only one shop open in London's Chinatown.  [Chinatown video: now vs. 2 months ago.]  Chinese people responded to coronavirus early; English government now has a policy.  Chinese and English experts formed a volunteer group sending Chinese medicine.  Chinese people are supplying elderly English with free facemasks.  [Journalist encourages cooperation.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't add comments to existing answers, while being pretty good, there are some small mistakes within the existing answer, so I'll post the entire transcript below, feel free to ask me any questions in the comment:

英国有近八十万的华侨华人群体，也是全球重要的留学目的地，有二十二万的中国留学生。疫情之下，在英华人的生活状况怎么样，华商的经营又受到了哪些冲击，来看欧洲时报英国负责人李强的观察。

疫情的确给在英的华人带来了方方面面的影响。有些华人表示，他们受到了歧视；英国中小学关闭、大学停课呢，使得很多留学生打乱了学习计划；餐饮业和旅游业，都是在英华人的支柱产业，也是受本次疫情影响最大的行业。疫情的持续蔓延也必将使得很多的华人的收入大打折扣。以伦敦的唐人街为例，这是最近的景象，只有华人超市还在正常经营，大量的餐厅已经停业，少数的餐厅呢还在提供外卖服务，但是整个街区非常的冷清。伦敦的唐人街位于市中心非常核心的位置，平时的人流量非常的大。这是朋友拍摄的两个月前伦敦的唐人街的景象，和今天的冷清形成了鲜明的对比。

面对疫情，特别是在早期，在英华人比英国民众有着更清晰的认识，我们很早就戴上了口罩。面对英国政府出台的全民居家隔离政策，在英的华人群体也更自觉地响应和支持。不仅如此，英国的华人还积极地向英国医疗机构捐款捐物。

面对疫情，在英的华人群体涌现出了很多值得敬佩的身影。在英的中医师们，自发地组织了“英国中医志愿抗疫行动”，为大家提供远程义诊，并为大家寄送抗疫中药；在英华人成立了志愿者组织，为有困难的侨胞和留学生朋友提供帮助。这是我今天在朋友圈看到的，一位十三岁的华人小留学生，选择在超市给老人的特定购物时段，在超市门口免费为英国的老人发放口罩。

病毒是可怕的，但是我相信只要大家保持乐观、共同努力，一定可以取得这场抗疫战争的胜利。

---

Edit: suggested edit trimmed down some punctuations, dropped several "呢" from the reporter's sentences, making the paragraph smoother to read, gratefully accepted :)

Comment: Thank you, I need to work on my listening

Comment: @dROOOze No problem at all, you've pretty much nailed all the important parts. Even as a native Mandarin speaker, I had to pause and listen again to what he said :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error :) yep it was a typo, apologies:)

Answer (score 3):

This guy doesn't enunciate clearly enough. Anyway...

1. ...的留学目的地，<s>又</s>有二十二万...
2. ...生活<s>中[huang3(?)]</s>狀況怎么...
3. ...华生的<s>[qing3ying3(?)]</s>經營又受到...
4. ...负责人<s>离长</s> Lǐ Qiáng (maybe 李強) 的观察
5. ...有些华人表示呢<s>？TA</s>们收到了歧视

   - ？ should be ，
   - TA should be 他 (TA們 is always 他們 unless you're certain that the people referred to is a group of exclusively female)
6. ...课呢<s>。</s>，使的很...
7. <s>财业和[liu2(?)]业</s>餐飲業和旅遊業
8. ...都<s>使</s>是在英华人...
9. ...在英华人的<s>[止住(?)]</s>支柱产业
10. ...是<s>说我们自己[xing2(?)]</s>受本次疫情影响最...
11. ...疫情的持续蔓延<s>的也比降[shi4(?)]的</s>呢，也必將使得很多...
12. ...收入<s>打的</s>大打折扣...
13. ...少数的餐厅呢<s>？这</s>，還在提供外卖服务...
14. ...区呢<s>，</s>非常的...
15. ...人街呢<s>？路是</s>，位于市中心非常...
16. ...平时的<s>正</s>人流量...
17. ...朋友<s>[拍手(?)]</s>拍攝的两个...
18. ...<s>[xing2(?)]成了[xian4(?)]面的对[pi(?)]</s>形成了鮮明的對比...
19. 面对疫情特别是<s>[dai4(?)]</s>在早期...
20. ...在英华人<s>的比，</s>呢，比...
21. ...英国民<s>中</s>眾...
22. ...更<s>亲情</s>親近的认识...
23. ...早了就<s>带</s>戴上了口罩...
24. ...的群体呢<s>？</s>，也更自...
25. ...捐款<s>[juan3(?)]</s>捐物...
26. ...华人的群体，<s>[卫生(?)]去了很多值得[qing4(?)]陪的[shen4yi4(?)]</s>...

    - I **think** this says: 有現出了很多值得敬佩的生意
27. ...在英的中<s>英</s>醫师门...
28. 的组织了<s>。</s>英国中医志
29. 家提供<s>原厂</s>遠程**医治**，并为大...

    - I cannot hear this part clearly, but I think it says 譯者 rather than 醫治
30. 在英<s>化人成为了志愿之</s>華人成立了志願者组织...
31. ...为有困难的<s>桥包</s>僑胞，和留...
32. ...在朋友<s>群</s>圈看到的...
33. ...<s>以为</s>一位十三岁的华人...
34. ...<s>可订</s>客訂购「物」时段...
35. ...相信<s>找</s>只要大家保...

---

Anyway, my transcription:

> 英國有近八十萬的華僑華人羣體，也是全球重要的留學目的地，有二十二萬的中國留學生，疫情之下在英華人的生活狀況怎麼樣？華生的經營又受到了哪些的衝擊，來看歐洲時報，英國負責人李強的觀察。
>
> 疫情的確給在英的華人帶來了方方面面的影響。有些華人表示呢，他們受到了歧視。英國中小學關閉，大學停課呢，使得很多留學生打亂了學習計劃，餐飲業和旅遊業都是在英華人的支柱產業，也是受本次疫情影響最大的行業。
>
> 疫情的持續蔓延呢，也必將使得很多華人的收入大打折扣。以倫敦的唐人街爲例，這是最近的景象，衹有華人超市還在正常經營，大量的餐廳已經停業。少數的餐廳呢，還在提供外賣服務，但是整個街區呢，非常地冷清。倫敦的唐人街呢，位于市中心非常核心的位置，平時的人流量非常地大。這是朋友拍攝兩個月前，倫敦的唐人街的景象。和今天的冷清，形成了鮮明的對比。
>
> 面對疫情特別是在早期，在英華人呢，比英國民眾有着更親近的認識。我們很早了就戴上了口罩，面對英國政府出臺的全民居家、隔離政策。在英華人的羣體呢，也更自覺地響應和支持，不僅如此呢，英國的華人還積極地向英國醫療機構，捐款捐物。
>
> 面對疫情呢，在英華人的羣體，有現出了很多值得敬佩的生意。在英的中醫師們，自發的組織了英國中醫志願抗疫行動，爲大家提供遠程譯者，竝爲大家寄送抗疫中藥。在英華人成立了志願者組織，爲有困難的僑胞，和留學生朋友提供幫助。
>
> 這是我今天在朋友圈看到的，一位十三歲的華人小留學生選擇在超市給老人的客訂購物時段，在超市門口呢，免費爲英國的老人發放口罩。
>
> 病毒是可怕的，但是我相信衹要大家保持樂觀、共同努力一定可以取得這場抗疫戰爭的勝利。

Comment: Yep, I have some remaining errors that I couldn't pick up. See others for corrections.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on @dROOOze's answer, but with more corrections:

1. "受到"了歧视
2. 更"清醒"的认识
3. “响应”
4. “涌现”出了
5. 远程“义诊”
6. 给老人的“特定”购物时段

(also cleared up some punctuations and tiny bits)

英国有近八十万的华侨华人群体，也是全球重要的留学目的地，有二十二万的中国留学生。疫情之下，在英华人的生活状况怎么样？华商的经营又受到了哪些的冲击？来看欧洲时报，英国负责人李强的观察。

疫情的确给在英的华人带来了方方面面的影响。有些华人表示他们受到了歧视。英国中小学关闭，大学停课，使得很多留学生打乱了学习计划。餐饮业和旅游业都是在英华人的支柱产业，也是受本次疫情影响最大的行业。

疫情的持续蔓延，也必将使得很多的华人的收入大打折扣。以伦敦的唐人街为例，这是最近的景象，只有华人超市还在正常经营，大量的餐厅已经停业。少数的餐厅还在提供外卖服务，但是整个街区非常的冷清。伦敦的唐人街位于市中心非常核心的位置，平时的人流量非常的大。这是朋友拍摄的两个月前伦敦的唐人街的景象，和今天的冷清形成了鲜明的对比。

面对疫情特别是在早期，在英华人比英国民众有着更清醒的认识。我们很早就戴上了口罩。面对英国政府出台的全民居家隔离政策，在英的华人群体也更自觉地响应和支持。不仅如此，英国的华人还积极地向英国医疗机构捐款捐物。

面对疫情，在英的华人群体涌现出了很多值得敬佩的生意。在英的中医师们自发地组织了英国中医志愿抗疫行动，为大家提供远程义诊，并为大家寄送抗疫中药。在英华人成立了志愿者组织，为有困难的侨胞和留学生朋友提供帮助。

这是我今天在朋友圈看到的，一位十三岁的华人小留学生选择在超市给老人的特定购物时段，在超市门口免费为英国的老人发放口罩。

病毒是可怕的，但是我相信，只要大家保持乐观，共同努力，一定可以取得这场抗疫战争的胜利。

Comment: This reporter uses too many 呢. I would drop all of them if it was an essay.

Comment: @TangHo Thanks for pointing out, I'll update it accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the 呢, because OP needs to get accurate transcription to understand that some of the 呢 is not 的 (they sound really similar if someone is mumbling). In normal essays or TV subtitles you wouldn't write 呢 in at all, but this isn't the situation to remove it.